# (c++) GetWindowText gives back empty value for everything except the console itself

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, console-application

I wan to to create a simple c++ console program that lets the user input the PID of a process, and the program will return the window title related to that PID. If there is no match, it defaults to "invalid".

The problem I have that the GetWindowText function seems to give me an empty value except for when i input the PID of the console itself.

The program seems to do it's job until it gets to the GetWindowText function.

I would be grateful if someone would help me figure this out.
I'm new to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question.
Thanks in advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int flag = 0;
WCHAR windowtitle[64] = L"Invalid";
DWORD inputpid;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND handle, LPARAM notinuse) {
DWORD gottenpid; 
LPDWORD gottenpidpointer = &gottenpid;

GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &gottenpid);
if (gottenpid == inputpid) {

    GetWindowText(handle, windowtitle, _countof(windowtitle));
    wprintf(L"The window title is: %ls.\n", windowtitle);
    flag = 1;
    return false;
}
return true;
}


int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv) {

    cout << "input pid:\n";
    cin >> inputpid;

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);

    if (flag == 0) {
        wprintf(L"The window title is: %ls.\n", windowtitle);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Have you tried checking the result of your various windows API calls then calling GetLastError if they fail?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) tells you, when `GetWindowText` returns a null string. For the full story, read [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833).

Comment: How are you getting the process ids that you enter? Keep in mind if you're using a program such as spy++ the ids are in hex so you will have to do `std::cin >> std::hex >> inputpid` Also I'm not sure if you need to be using `wchar` since `GetWindowText` doesn't normally return one. Other than that, I tested your code (without using `wchar`) and got it to work.

Comment: @Salamosaurus it does if you are using a unicode build and therefore `GetWindowTextW` rather than `GetWindowTextA`

Comment: @Salamosaurus: There is no conceivable reason to *not* use a Unicode build, especially when querying for strings that are outside your control. I wouldn't know how the system deals with a situation, where it needs to return an ANSI string, when the source string contains characters that cannot be represented in the currently active code page. Not even getting into the wasted resources, and arbitrary limits stemming from constantly converting between different character sets. If `GetWindowText` doesn't return a wide character string for you, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Console window can be child process of conhost.exe Maybe you are not getting the right PID